# react-router: How do I update the url without causing a navigation/reload?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

With react router I have done this up update the url:

```
this.props.history.push({
    pathname: `/product/${this.props.product.id}`,
});
```

However this causes a re-render/navigation change. Is there a way to update the URL without doing that?

My use case is I have a list of products and when I click on one I show a Modal and want to update the URL to something like `example.com/product/1` so that the link is sharable.

Comment: This is all built into react-router; it's called [dynamic routing](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/guides/philosophy)

Comment: i don't believe this is currently possible in react-router v6, there is an open issue: https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/issues/8908

Answer (score 101):

Wasn't able to find a solution using React Router, but was able to accomplish this using the browser's history interface by calling:

```js
window.history.replaceState(null, "New Page Title", "/pathname/goes/here")
```

You can learn more about `.replaceState` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState).

**React Router's `history.replace` won't always work**

React Router's `history.replace` method may or may not trigger a re-render depending on your app's route setup (e.g., you have a catch-all `/*` route). It does not prevent a render by definition.

Comment: Beware that this change might bypass React Router's knowledge of the current path if it is again modified later. E.G. if you append 1 sub path using this method and then use RR to navigate up 1 level, it will visually jump 2 because RR still thinks the location is without the appended sub path.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the OP and solved it using his approach. Many thanks! @MagnusBull for browser history I simply use `window.history.pushState(stringify(currentParams), "");` and that seems to do the trick though I haven't encountered the sub path issue you spoke about

Comment: @usr28765526 My point is that if you use React Router to handle navigation, then using the browser API `replaceState` can be considered a "hack" and RR will not know that the path changed. If you try to use React Router's `location` after the URL has been modified, it will operate on the version of the URL it knows about: The one before the change. This can be unpredictable and confusing.

Comment: So helpful, thank you! Did not know history.replace could cause re-renders

Answer (score 9):

replace will override the URL

```
this.props.history.replace({ pathname: `/product/${this.props.product.id}`})
```

Comment: That definitely still causes the Router to act upon, and then there is a blank screen (i guess it cant find a route)

Comment: really, replace should only override the URL

Comment: I found ths that works: window.history.replaceState(null, null, `/product/${this.props.product.id}`);

Comment: react-router replace should behave like replaceState. I can confirm that replace does not trigger a render, check this small demo https://jsbin.com/jinazirowa/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This should work without refreshing/rerendering, as long as the Router path encapsulates the new path.

Answer (score 2):

I am a ReactJS newbie, but can't you use [Shallow routing in React Router to change the URL of a page without reloading it](https://medium.com/@codingscenes/shallow-routing-is-a-feature-provided-by-react-router-8d134e209a1d) as shown in the copy-pasted code snippet below?

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

function MyComponent() {
  const history = useHistory();

  function handleClick() {
    history.push('/my-page', { shallow: true });
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Go to My Page</button>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -3):

I'm using a nice way of tricking the users that's the URL doesn't change.

To do this, you'll just need to setup your routes like this.

```
const Home = '/';
const About = '/ ';
const Contact = '/  ';
```

Notice the spaces. All characters will be counted inside the quote so it should work.

`Routes.tsx`

```
<Route exact path={Home} component={Home} />
<Route exact path={About} component={About} />
<Route exact path={Contact} component={Contact} />
```

Inside your `About.tsx` and `Contact.tsx`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    window.history.replaceState(null, '', Home);
  }, []);
```

After the user navigates to `About` or `Contact` pages, the hook will be called and run the code inside the callback function. It will remove the spaces after the component rendered.

That should be clean trick to disguise hidden URL

Comment: This is basically the Whitespace version of URLs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_(programming_language)

Comment: unlike any other answer, you'll notice a sec within a flicker everytime location changes. my client hated that one as well so i used a trick. consider my answer above a 

Comment: @NivekMozart The problem with this code is that it drastically reduces readability and greatly enhances the chances of human error. You can stop flickering without playing whitespace golf.