# How do i change app path without reloading app

Tags: javascript, browser, frontend

I want the code injected by my chrome extension to update the users pathname without reloading the users app.

Currently i've got a work around

```
window.history.pushState('', '', '/about')
setTimeout(() => window.history.back(), 10)
setTimeout(() => window.history.forward(), 20)
window.history.pushState('', '', '/about')
```

Is there a better way of doing this ? maybe i don't understand history state well enough.

Comment: have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101831/react-router-how-do-i-update-the-url-without-causing-a-navigation-reload

Answer (score 1):

`window.history.replaceState("", "", "/data")` this changes the path without reloading the page but you have to handle the page refresh on the index file

and you can append new data by

`window.history.replaceState("", "", "/data"); fetch('DataPage.html').then((res) => res.text()).then(res => {document.querySelector("#target").innerHTML = res;})`

You have to place a element with id like `<div id="target"></div>`

Comment: That changes the path but doesn't navigate anywhere. Is there a way of navigating without triggering a hard reload.

Comment: i have edit the answer it would probably helps you