# How to prevent React Router DOM from scrolling page to top on navigate replace state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

When I am doing this:

```
navigate(
  `${window.location.pathname}?query=${encodeURIComponent(
    JSON.stringify(q)
  )}`,
  { replace: true }
);
```

If I scroll down a little from the page, then change a `<Select />` input value, which triggers an update to this query in the URL, react-router-dom is scrolling the page to the top. When I remove this `navigate` code and change the select inputs, no jumping to the page top occurs, so it must be react-router-dom somehow. How do I disable or prevent this "jump to page top" behavior in react-router-dom?

Comment: Do you use code like `window.scrollTo(0, 0);` in a place of your code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router: How do I update the url without causing a navigation/reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101831/react-router-how-do-i-update-the-url-without-causing-a-navigation-reload)

Comment: Why are you not using the [`useSearchParams`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usesearchparams) hook to update the `query` queryString parameter value? Can you also update your question to include/provide a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I don't know what could be causing it, but don't think I am using `window.scrollTo` anywhere. I tried switching to `useSearchParams` but didn't fix it. The linked question doesn't answer it either. I can't produce a working example, this is part of a huge app.

Comment: Ah yes actually, it appears somewhere else deep in the app we are doing `scrollTo(0, 0)` on navigation change. How can I only do it on path change not query param change?

Comment: I just did a double check that only the path changed, not the search params. Thanks for the tips!

Comment: The URL queryString (search) isn't part of the URL path and isn't considered when route path matching. It will be part of any `location` object that changes, so if the `scrollTo` logic isn't looking specifically at the `pathname` value changing it could perhaps be indirectly triggering the scrolling action.