# How change url in react, without rerender app

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have page with tabs.

```
{
  path: '/settings/monitoring/:tab',
  component: MonitoringPage,
  exact: true,
  type: PRIVATE_TYPE,
},
```

There is `useEffect`, which get data for all tabs. There is function, which change tab:

```
const onChangeTab = (tabName) => {
  const tab = findTab(tabName)
  props.history.push(tab.settings.name, null)
  setSettings(tab.settings)
}
```

`history.push` change link, but also rerender app and `useEffect` work again. History push need to have access to tabs with link, how can I fix it, but have access to tabs with link?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [react-router: How do I update the url without causing a navigation/reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57101831/react-router-how-do-i-update-the-url-without-causing-a-navigation-reload)

Comment: What tabs? What `useEffect` hook? Your question makes little since because navigating to a new route will likely trigger a rerender, and enqueueing a state update will certainly trigger a rerender. Please edit your post to include a [mcve] so we've context for what any code is doing and what any issue possibly is.

Answer (score 0):

Did you put dependency in the `useEffect`?

```js
useEffect(() => {
//.... 
}, [tabName])
```

This will make the useEffect to run only when `tabName` is changed and not when it is re-rendered.